# Compatibility issue between SQL Server and Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

I think you can help me.
I am developing an application for a small company. I have been working on Visual Studio 2015 with a SQL Server 2014 database and I have made a noob mistake. My app was almost finished but I discovered that the company has only one server with Windows Server 2003 on it, and it is not possible to update it.
Windows Server 2003 works up to SQL Server 2008 so I have tried but it has been impossible to me to attach my database to SQL Server 2008 (even changing compatibility level to 100) or connecting a new 2008 database to the application in Visual Studio 2015.
I do not know what to do now. Is there some possibility to make that my database works? Or is any other DBMS that would be better to work with my 2015 app in my 2003 server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database in production SQL Server 2008, then
create a Linked Server on your production Server to your development SQL Server 2014 and copy all the tables / procedures / functions over.
[How to Create a Linked Server](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=bulk%20import%20file%20size%20limit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_uAvV4jWKrTM8gfghpvoDQ#q=create%20linked%20server)

Answer (score 0):

Backup/restore works with older backup/newer restore server. Detach/attach do the same. The best solution here is to script developer DB (make sure you don't include newest features not supported by the production server) and run on production. If you want to move data as well, it is better to create at least two separate .sql's, one for schema and another for data.